# Redirect intent on Dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a "Welcome" intent in Dialogflow, which shows the user various options such as "Breakfast Menu" or "Dinner Menu". I'm thinking about adding an option so that when a user misclicks one of the menus and they type "Return", they can be sent back to the options shown in the "Welcome" intent. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [follow-up intents](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/contexts-follow-up-intents) to manage this kind of behavior. Specifically the predefined "[previous](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/reference/follow-up-intent-expressions#:%7E:text=or%20select%20items.-,previous,-Common%20expressions%20to)" child intent.